# VS Code JSON Format Reverts on File Change

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know you can format on demand, save etc. However, I want my JSON files to be formatted automatically when I open them.

I'm currently using Prettier for my default formatter; which works great when I force the formatting through ctrl+shift+p > format document or just pressing ctrl+s does it (because I have that enabled).

I forgot to mention that if I have the file open in the editor (no pending changes) and the file is updated from a source outside of the editor, the formatting resets.

How can I prevent the formatting from resetting after the file is updated?
Does anyone have this working and if so how?

Comment: Thanks, though do you mean the shortcut for "Format Document"? The ctrl+shift+p command is what you use to bring up the command palette. I do see under the When expression there is an entry for `editorHasFocus`. Is that what I should be looking for?

Comment: Apologies. I updated the question to be more specific as what I'm looking for. I think with your answer it wouldn't matter either way.

Comment: Forgive me, but I might be missing something in your comment. I can format the document easily enough (save, alt+shift+f, etc). But, when the file is updated outside the editor, the formatting changes back to single line. How can this be avoided and have the formatting stick.